# Why would mod_wsgi be serving sporadic 500 errors?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I was having issues with my Django app (running on Debian with Apache 2.2.22) serving occasional bursts of 500 errors with the mod_wsgi "Premature Script exit" errors in the logs. I dug around and it looked like the crashes might be a result of running out of memory, as a result I found a bad memory hog bug and fixed it. However at the same time I was reading about mod_wsgi configs and decided to make a couple other changes to my setup. I added...

```
stack-size=524288 maximum-requests=500 inactivity-timeout=5
```

to my Apache config, making it look like this...

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/src/myapp-api/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=me group=team processes=4 threads=16 stack-size=524288 maximum-requests=500 inactivity-timeout=5 python-path=/home/myapp/src/myapp-api:/home/myapp/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

I tested it out on my dev servers and all seemed fine, but once I deployed this to servers under more load I saw a large number of sporadic 500 errors, again logging "Premature Script exit" but this time there was no memory issues and the system had plenty of free RAM.

I'm at a loss as to what caused this. The only other error that was new in the logs was

```
[Wed Jan 14 20:17:16 2015] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'" in <bound method TCPTransport.__del__ of <amqp.transport.TCPTransport object at 0x7ff4b0e69d10>> ignored
```

which seems to relate to my usage of Celery and AMQP, so perhaps this is a problem with C module interop?

If the stack size issue was a problem I would expect to see errors in my django code, not in mod_wsgi, so what else could cause this?

Comment: Have you ever read this. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Comment: BTW, running maximum-requests=500 inactivity-timeout=5 in production is a bad idea as it will effect CPU load and capacity due to frequent restarts.

Comment: I've tried setting the WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL} but when I do it fails to find the right python modules from my virtualenv and i've been unable to get it to work. 

I set the max-requests and inactivity timeout because I was seeing memory use of the workers grow slowly over time and I thought it would keep things stable while I hunt for the leak.

The service has been running without issue for two years with these WSGI settings, i'm not sure why adding these three parameters would cause new errors. My app does use a few python C extension modules but none of the ones you listed.

Comment: I'm also curious why the timestamps for my 500 errors are many hours earlier than when they actually get written to the logs.

Comment: That document does not say to use 'WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}'. It says to use 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'. Time stamps can be different because Apache may be logging at UTC while you are looking at local walk clock time.

Comment: Well that might explain part of my problem.

Comment: As for the timestamps, it's not a UTC thing. I can see it happen when I tail the logs, lines listing 500 errors are written to the log at 2pm with a timestamp of 8am, the lines directly above and below have 2pm timestamps. I was assuming that the wsgi process died and Apache has some form of long timeout before it writes the log lines?

Comment: No, it is a timezone issue. This is a known problem caused by web applications changing the timezone of the process after it has started during application initialisation. The result is that early log messages from a process will be with what ever timezone Apache as a whole was running under, possibly UTC, but possibly something else. After the web application has changed the timezone, they change to that. Is the timezone in Django settings correct, or the default. Does it match what Apache uses?

Comment: My timezones are correct in Django and this is not just at application init time. The app has been running for a long time when these errors hit and it's only the 500 errors that appear to have this issue. While watching the logs I see a bunch of 500 log lines dumped into the log seemingly at the same time, all with varying timestamps from the last few hours. It's not a consistent time offset, it's different for each line entry.

Comment: Since you are using daemon mode, 500 errors coming from Apache child worker processes and not mod_wsgi daemon mode will still be the original timezone. Anyway, there is no point continuing to discuss here as this isn't what StackOverflow is for. If you want to really understand it better, use the mod_wsgi mailing list and provide the actual details of the messages so they can be looked at properly.